# Linq to XML: How do you determine if something of type "var" is null or empty?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So, I've got a small chunk of stabby, pointy xml that looks like this:

```
<Groups UseGroup='True'>
     <Group>1264,182,1979</Group>
</Groups>
```

And I've got a small chunk of linq that gets the value from  that looks like this:

```
var group = from a in xml.Descendants("Groups")
         select a.Element("Group").Value;
```

It's all fine and dandy but I don't know how to handle a null response?  If I use:

```
if(group != null)
```

It will always evaluate `true` because there is something there.  If I use:

```
if(group.ToString() == "")
```

It will always evaluate true because ToString() called on that object returns System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String] For some reason, I'm having a hard time casting my result from my linq query to a string so I'm using var because that seems to be the only way I can get it to work...

So the question is, am I using the correct linq syntax and if so, how do i tell if it returned anything or not?

Comment: You're having problems because you don't understand the most important fact about queries: the value of the query is THE QUERY. "group" refers to an object which represents the logical operation of "project these values from this collection". "group" will never be null; it's an object which represents that operation, and that object will never be null.

Comment: If what you want to ask is "does this query return any results?", then use a sequence operator on the query. "group.Any()" for example executes the query and returns true if it returned at least one value, or false if it returned no values.

Comment: But let me just repeat this to make sure it is clear: the result of a query expression is the query, not the results of the query. If you want the results of the query then you're going to have to do more than just create the query. You're going to have to execute it in some way.

Comment: Ah, thanks Eric, that helps a lot - I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why Eric posted his answer as a comment, but he's correct. Your conditional statement should read:

```
if (group.Any())
```

If your XML has no "Groups" tags, then `Any()` will evaluate to false.

You can think of `group` as being a sequence of all the matches to your query. In your example, there's only one match, but that just means it's an IEnumerable with only one value. To get that value, you can do:

```
string groupVal = group.FirstOrDefault();
```

That will return the first match, or a null string if there are no matches. You can use `Single()` if you want there to be exactly one result, and you want to throw an exception if there are zero or many results. There are also `First()` and `SingleOrDefault()` methods that behave as you might expect.